# TextFSM nxos template

Tags: parsing, python-textfsm

I have started exploring [TextFSM](https://github.com/google/textfsm) by google, its great for screen scraping. But I'm stuck. 
Here is the template for the command: "show ip community-list"

```
Value TYPE (Standard|Extended)
Value CLNAME (\D+)
Value SEQ (\d+)
Value ACTION (permit|deny)
Value ASNUM (\d+)
Value TAGNUM (\d+)

Start
  ^${TYPE}\s+Community\s+List\s+${CLNAME}\s+ -> Community

Community
  ^\s+${SEQ}\s+${ACTION}\s+${ASNUM}\s+:\s+${TAGNUM}\s+ -> Record Start
```

Raw output looks like:

```
Expanded Community List ROUTES_CL1
1 permit "11111:10000"
Standard Community List ROUTES_CL2
    1 permit 11111:10000
    2 permit 22222:10000
    3 permit 33333:10000
```

somereason doesn't parse into key and values.

Answer (score 0):

There are several things which need to be fixed:

- Extended (in your template) vs Expanded (in your output)
- CLNAME has digits in it which won't be matched by \D+
- \s+:\s+ requires spaces around the colon which the output doesn't have
- The Community List name needs to be remembered as there may be multiple action lines to which it applies. Use "Filldown".

Using this template:

```
Value Filldown TYPE (Standard|Extended|Expanded)
Value Filldown CLNAME (\w+)
Value SEQ (\d+)
Value ACTION (permit|deny)
Value ASNUM (\d+)
Value TAGNUM (\d+)

Start 
  ^${TYPE}\s+Community\s+List\s+${CLNAME} 
  ^\s*${SEQ}\s+${ACTION}\s+"?${ASNUM}:${TAGNUM}"? -> Next.Record

EOF
```

Will give the parsed output of:

```
[['Expanded', 'ROUTES_CL1', '1', 'permit', '11111', '10000'],
 ['Standard', 'ROUTES_CL2', '1', 'permit', '11111', '10000'],
 ['Standard', 'ROUTES_CL2', '2', 'permit', '22222', '10000'],
 ['Standard', 'ROUTES_CL2', '3', 'permit', '33333', '10000']]
```

A similar example with further explanation can be found on the [textfsm wiki](https://github.com/google/textfsm/wiki/Code-Lab#using-list).